# Where is the 'indeterminate type'?

Tags: f#

I'm defining the following type extension:

```
type System.Reflection.MemberInfo with
    member x.GetAttribute<'T when 'T :> Attribute>(required, inherit') =
        match required, Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof<'T>, inherit') with
        | true, null -> invalidOp (sprintf "Missing required attribute: %s" typeof<'T>.FullName)
        | _, attr -> attr :> 'T
```

The last match expression (`attr :> 'T`) gives the error:

*The static coercion from Attribute to 'T involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Static coercions are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed.*

I've tried annotating the function return type, but got the same result. I would hate to change this to a dynamic cast. Is there a way to make the static cast work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be a dynamic cast, right?  You have an object whose static type is `System.Attribute`, and you want to downcast it to its actual concrete type.

```
open System
type System.Reflection.MemberInfo with 
  member x.GetAttribute<'T when 'T :> Attribute>(required, inherit') =  // '
    match required, Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof<'T>, inherit') with 
    | true, null -> invalidOp (
        sprintf "Missing required attribute: %s" typeof<'T>.FullName)  // '
    | _, attr -> attr :?> 'T
```

Comment: I suppose so. I think I was thrown off by similar code in C#, where dynamic and static casts have the same syntax. It must be dynamic casting in C# too.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the meaning of the error message - the compiler makes a difference between static cast `:>` (which is always safe, e.g. casting from `Random` to `Object`) and dynamic cast `:?>` (which may fail).

In your case, you need to use dynamic cast. This is what the compiler means:

- It says that *"The static coercion from Attribute to `'T` involves an indeterminate type"*. This means that it doesn't know (at compile-time) what is the actual type used in place of the generic parameter `'T`.
- As a result, the compiler cannot check whether the conversion from `Attribute` to `'T` will always succeed (which is required in case of static coercions). If the compiler, for example, determined that the type of `'T` will be always `Object`, then the use of static coercion would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code, in case it benefits anyone (Brian's code is right too...I just prefer the type annotation in the signature):

```
type System.Reflection.MemberInfo with
    member x.GetAttribute<'T when 'T :> Attribute>(required, inherit') : 'T =
        match required, Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof<'T>, inherit') with
        | true, null -> invalidOp (sprintf "Missing required attribute: %s" typeof<'T>.FullName)
        | _, attr -> downcast attr
```